# js.erb not rendering in rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m having trouble rendering a .js.erb from an action. The action triggers, and rails tells me that it’s rendering the js.erb, but the js never gets rendered and is evident from the console logs in the js not rendering to the browser’s console. I’ve tried a bunch of solutions online but can’t seem to find out why rails would be telling me this js template is rendering, but not have it actually render in the browser.
What could I be missing?

Controller action

```
def dynamic_search
    puts "WE ARE IN DYNAMIC_SEARCH"
    puts params[:q]
    client = HTTPClient.new
    string = 'call to google places api'
    @result = client.get_content(string)
    @hash = JSON.parse @result

    render "home/dynamic_search.js.erb", format: :js
  end
```

Rails terminal output

```
  Rendering home/dynamic_search.js.erb
  Rendered home/dynamic_search.js.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Completed 200 OK in 479ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4613)
```

UPDATE:

Code that calls the action is below (not 100% correct but just testing the call at the moment using JQuery easy-autocomplete)

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

    $input = $('*[data-behavior="autocomplete"]')

    var options = {
        url: function(phrase){
            console.log(phrase)
            return '/search/' + phrase
        }
    }

    $input.easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

Comment: can you share the code from `dynamic_search.js.erb` ?  There aren;t any errors or anything is just renders a blank page?  Could you also give a sample URL that you tried that didn't work?

Comment: How are you getting to this page? `dynamic_search` makes it sound like this might be an AJAX call that you are just not handling. Rails is clearly rendering that page so we are going to need more details to determine where your issue is.

Comment: I'm working with the contributor here:

can you share the code from dynamic_search.js.erb ? 

It just consists of a `console.log('here')`.

This is rendered after an action is hit in rails triggered from jquery. The page is loaded, the jquery hits the action, the action renders in rails and expects to render `dynamic_search.js.erb` (and rails reports that it rendered it) .but the javascript never touches the browser.  In fact, we were unable to find `dynamic_search.js.erb` in sources via chrome inspector.

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree are you actually visiting "/some/path/dynamic_search.js" or is this loaded from another page. If another page please post code showing how it is being loaded.

Comment: It's being loaded from another page. Please see updated description. 1. User lands on page, which loads jquery script to `/search/x`. 2. Rails routes `/search/x` to `dynamic_search`. 3 `dynamic_search` renders `dynamic_search.js.erb` (which has a console log and an `alert()`) but the console log nor alert is never seen on the front end (double checked browser log filters, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`easy-autocomplete` is expecting `dynamic_search` to return parsable data either (JSON or XML).

It is not actually running the js in "dynamic_search.js.erb" in the current context. This means that either the content of "dynamic_search.js.erb" needs to represent such an object after rendering or preferably the `dynamic_search` action should just render it directly.

For Example (I will assume you want to use `easy-autocomplete` with `@result`)

```
def dynamic_search
    puts "WE ARE IN DYNAMIC_SEARCH"
    puts params[:q]
    client = HTTPClient.new
    string = 'call to google places api'
    @result = client.get_content(string)

    render json: @result
  end
```

I am not sure what the `@result` json actually looks like so you may need additional manipulation above or below.

Then the js could be:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $input = $('*[data-behavior="autocomplete"]')
    var options = {
        url: function(phrase){
            console.log(phrase)
            return `/search/${phrase}`
        }
    }
    $input.easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

Comment: This almost works! the json does render as expected, but the template (`dynamic_search.js.erb`) does not render (nor does rails output tell us that the template was rendered. How can we tell it to also render `dynamic_search.js.erb` in the `def dynamic_search` action?

Comment: Looking closer at the problem, we have exactly what's going on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437247/rails-js-erb-not-working. Could it be that we need to denote some `:remote => true` in a form submission, rather than calling the action through `/search/ + phrase`?

Comment: What are you expecting to "render"? The url for easyAutocomplete is just to supply data to the `$input` it is not intended to change the contents of the page at all otehr than the list for the auto completion

Comment: FWIW, the issue here was `:remote => true`. Rails forms require this for the jquery to work upon form submission.